# How Can I check my server and magento site is PCI Compliance

Tags: magento, pci-compliance

Is there any tool to check the PCI Compliance of the site and server.

Also that will be great if I know how can I make my server and magento site PCI Compliance.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2):

Only a certified PCI Quality Security Assessor can certify that your site is PCI compliance or not.
Please visit [Qualified Security Assessors](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/assessors_and_solutions/qualified_security_assessors)

Nexpose can be used as a tool.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many factors to make the site PCI Compliant.
As @muk mentioned, Only certified PCI Quality Assessor can scan your site and give you a report.

The report contains vulnerabilities and solutions to fix the vulnerabilities.

For most common vulnerabilities are (Basic things to be PCI Compliant):

1. SSL Certificate with TLS 1.1, SHA1 with RSA
2. X-Frame-Options should be from same origin
3. Cookies without httponly, secure flags
4. Directory permissions in your webserver
5. Payment modules should be PCI Complaint
6. if you're using Captcha in your forms that should be PCI Compliant

So on..

you'll get to know your site specific issues once you get PCI Scan Report

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for a free trial for Qualys PCI Compliance on the following [link][1]. You can use it for scanning your website for internal purposes but as @Muk mentioned, only certified PCI Quality Assessor can certify the PCI compliance.